# Pulling a Textfield Value using a CustomCell File

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textfield

I have a subclass, CustomCell, which inherits from my parent class, CreateEvent. The subclass describes the individual cells for the table view cell, which is on the CreateEvent View controller. In one specific cell, I have a textfield, that is linked to the CustomCell file, but I am having trouble getting the value from that textfield when a user enters into the textfield. I am also having trouble dismissing the keyboard with outside touches and pressing the return key, but I am primarily focused on getting the text from the textfield. I am familiar with doing these functionalities on ONE normal swift file but because this is a subclass and two swift files, I'm not sure what to do. This is my code:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var entranceFeeTextField: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
     super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

and

```
class CreateEventVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

// the following code describes the array for an expandable drop down 
if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellNormal" {
    if let primaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = primaryTitle as? String
    }

    eventType = ((cellDescriptors[0] as! NSMutableArray)[0] as! NSDictionary)["primaryTitle"]! as! String
    if let secondaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["secondaryTitle"] {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = secondaryTitle as? String
    }
}
else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellTextfield" {
    cell.textField.placeholder = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
}


else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellValuePicker" {
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
}

cell.delegate = self

return cell
}


func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField:UITextField) -> Bool {
entranceFeeAmount = cell.entranceFeeTextField.text!

return true;
}

}
```

My main question is whether I am conforming to the UITextField Delegates properly, because I am not able to print out the value of the entranceFeeTextField. I have not been able to get an answer that solves my problem, or one that I can understand.

Comment: directly you can write ' entranceFeeAmount = textField.text ' in textFieldShouldEndEditing method

Comment: You need to set delegate for UITextField to current view controller in cellForRowAt to use the delegate methods in you'r current view controller.

Comment: @yagneshdobariya I can't do that because I didn't set the IBOutlet to the CreateEventVC, so that line of code won't recognize the entranceFeeTextField. I have it linked to the CustomCell file

Comment: @AnkitaShah I am new to xcode swift. Could you explain further? Do I need to put cell.textField.delegate = self ?

Comment: Add cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: @yagneshdobariya I get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value [Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION]

Answer (score 0):

Just assign delegate to the textfield inside the cell where it class is `CustomCell`

```
cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self
```

but make sure the `cell` have correct identifier and correct class

Comment: what exactly is cell in cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate? In my code I set: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

Comment: @Kevin so have you set that delegate to textfield?

Comment: it gave me an error when I put in cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self into the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

You need to add selector method to your textfield as below.

```
txtEntrance.addTarget(self, action:#selector(textFieldEndEditings(sender:)), for:.editingDidEnd)

func textFieldEndEditings(sender:UITextField) -> Void 
{
   print(sender.text)
}
```

Comment: which file do I put this code in? What does this selector method do?

Comment: this selector method put in your custom class . this selector called while your textfield do end editing.

Comment: and also you can add this selector method in your tableVies's cellForRowAtIndexPath.